# CodeIgniter Delete where condition and where not in given array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, query-builder

How to run delete query in Codeigniter. I have set of array and a key. In MySQL my query run perfectly.

```
DELETE FROM `TABLE` WHERE `style_id`=2 && `ID` NOT IN (5,9,12)
```

In Codeigniter how to write and run this query. I tried below code but not working.

```
$ids = '5,9,12';
$this->db->where('style_id', $style_id)->where_not_in('ID', $ids);
$this->db->delete('TABLE');
```

Comment: please show me the $id 's value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: you must have **$ids** as array

```
$ids = array(5,9,12);
$style_id= 2;


$this->db->where('style_id', $style_id);
$this->db->where_not_in('ID', $ids);
$this->db->delete('TABLE');
```

Comment: Please remove extra `->` in `$this->db->->where_not_in('ID', $ids);`

Comment: I tried but it deleted whole record. Please check my mysql query.

Comment: So what you want to try to delete?

Comment: Thanks. I got my mistake. Issue was, i was having string.

Comment: why it's get downvoted ? @Downvoter can you please explain .so that i can correct my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can write this in single line if you want to like this:

```
$this->db->delete('table name',array('field1'=>'value1','field2 !='=>'value2'));
```

short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this->db->where('style_id', $style_id);
this->db->where_not_in('ID', $ids);
$this->db->delete('TABLE');
```

This will join two arguments with `AND` clause

---

And Data  should be

**array**

```
$ids = array(10, 20, '30);
```

**Id**

```
$style_id = 15;
```

Read [Looking for Specific Data in codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Comment: `$this->db->where('style_id', $style_id)->where_not_in('ID', $ids);` this will bid dta with `OR` clause

Comment: I tried but it deleted whole record. Please check my mysql query.

Comment: what are you trying to do? explain please with respective data

Answer (score 0):

You can run this directly :

```
DELETE FROM `TABLE` WHERE `style_id`=2 && `ID` NOT IN (5,9,12)
in $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `TABLE` WHERE `style_id`=2 && `ID` NOT IN (5,9,12)");
```

Answer (score 0):

// Try it

```
$ids = array(5,9,12);
$style_id =2;
$this->db->where('ID', $style_id);
$this->db->where_not_in('ID', $ids);
$this->db->delete('TABLE');
```

Comment: I tried but it deleted whole record. Please check my mysql query.

Comment: check again @BhuneshSatpada